# How to do an inverse border-radius with a drop shadow?

Tags: css

I'm working on a webpage with `<div>` elements that are separated like this:

**Picture of the separator**

[image: picture of the separator]

I've tried using clip-path, pseudo-elements, SVGs - but I can't find a way to have a transition with an inner border-shadow and an "inverse" border-radius.
Has anybody managed to make something like this using CSS?

Here's my current code (and a [CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/maxencelav/pen/bGWrWQN)):

```css
body {
  background: grey;
}

#container {
  background: white;
  /* Same as the #sec2 background */
}

.section {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

#sec1 {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0em 30px #00000033;
  border-radius: 0em 0em 0em 4em;
}

#sec2 {
  border-radius: 0em 4em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <section id="sec1" class="section">
      [content]
    </section>
    <section id="sec2" class="section">
      [other content]
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
```